# Does $\Bbb{Z}\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\right)/\Bbb{Z}$ form a torsion group under addition modulo $1$?

Tags: group-theory

> Does $\Bbb{Z}\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\right)/\Bbb{Z}$ form a torsion group under addition modulo $1$?

It looks like it does based on checking a few numbers.

I know the group axioms and I know the condition for a group to be torsion is that every element has finite order but I've not seen an example of applying the rules to show a certain group is a group and is torsion.

Comment: Title question: Is $\Bbb Z(\frac13,\frac12)$ an abelian group? Is $\Bbb Z$ a subgroup thereof? -- Body question: Is $\Bbb Z(\frac13,\frac12)$ a subgroup of $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen well I'm thinking addition modulo $1$ is commutative for starters. That perhaps gives a clue as to my level of ineptitude.

Comment: I've noticed the question in the title and in the body are slightly different. Do you already know whether this is a group and are just asking whether it's torsion, or would you like an argument as for why it's a group as well?

Comment: @Wojowu sorry I need an argument for both.

Comment: What is $\Bbb Z(\frac13,\frac12)$?

Comment: @lhf I intended $\Bbb{Z}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3})$ to be the smallest ring extension of $\Bbb{Z}$ that contains $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose $R=\Bbb Z\left(\frac 12,\frac 13\right)=\Bbb Z\left(\frac 16\right)$ is the sub**ring** of $\Bbb Q$ generated by $\frac 16$. (Also the localization of $\Bbb Z$ w.r.t. multiplicative system of powers of $6$.) As such it is a ring, and it comes with two operations, $+$ and $\cdot\ $ (the ring operations). With respect to $+$, it is an abelian group. Then $\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $R$. So $A=R/\Bbb Z$ makes sense, it is the quotient group, so by definition a group. Let now $a\in A$ be an element. It can be lifted to an element of $R$, so there is a fraction  $r=m/6^k\in R\subset \Bbb Q$ lifting $a$. Obviuosly, $m=6^kr\in \Bbb Z$ is a lift of $6^ka$, so $a$ is a torsion element. (Explicitly, $6^ka=0$ in $A$.)

Comment: Thanks. Is $R(a,b)$ always $R(ab)$ if $a,b$ are coprime?